# Can you inject a custom exception (or its provider)?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

The standard [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) has no default constructor (or a way to set the message after instantiation). If a custom exception is based on it, can the derived class be made injectable?

```
public class SpecialPurposeException extends Exception {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public SpecialPurposeException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

The custom exception will not normally be instantiated outside of its module, but for consistency reasons it should perhaps be injected inside of it.

Comment: Why do you want to Inject into an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There **is** a no-args for `Exception`.  See [`Exception()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28%29).
2. You cannot modified the value of the message `String` in `Exception`, but you can override the `getMessage()` method to return something different.  That should be sufficient to allow you to inject a message ... in various ways.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Regarding the default constructor, I was obviously in error.